# Trying to find previous DOM elements and get input value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a table that when a user click update, it will get the first and second input value. I am trying to use prev to find the first two DOM element and get the value, but fail, what should I do? Any help is appreciated.

```js
$('.update_button').on("click",function(){
 var update_val_1 = $(this).prev().find('input:first').val();
 var update_val_2 = $(this).prev().find('input:nth-child(2)').val();

 alert(update_val_1);
 alert(update_val_2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="gridtable">
    <td><input type="text" value="apple" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="one" /></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridtable">
    <td><input type="text" value="banana" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="three" /></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridtable">
    <td><input type="text" value="berry" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="ten" /></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) looks for *sibling* nodes. Your `input` elements are in different `td`'s so they aren't siblings. Instead, you need to go to the parent row then grab the `input`s from there.

Explicit example:

```js
$('.update_button').on("click", function() {
  var $parentRow = $(this).closest('.gridtable');
  var $firstCell = $parentRow.find('td:first-child');
  var $secondCell = $parentRow.find('td:nth-child(2)');
  var $firstInput = $firstCell.find('input');
  var $secondInput = $secondCell.find('input');
  var update_val_1 = $firstInput.val();
  var update_val_2 = $secondInput.val();

  console.log(update_val_1);
  console.log(update_val_2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="gridtable">
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="apple" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="one" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gridtable">
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="banana" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="three" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gridtable">
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="berry" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="ten" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Simplified example:

```js
$('.update_button').on("click", function() {
  var $parentRow = $(this).closest('.gridtable');
  var update_val_1 = $parentRow.find('td:first-child input').val();
  var update_val_2 = $parentRow.find('td:nth-child(2) input').val();

  console.log(update_val_1);
  console.log(update_val_2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="gridtable">
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="apple" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="one" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gridtable">
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="banana" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="three" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gridtable">
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="berry" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="ten" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="update_button">UPDATE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the **.closest(selector)** and **.find('selector')** methods.

The first one goes up the dom until it finds the first match of the given selector.

The second one goes down the dom and finds all matches.

**.eq(index)** is like array[index] for jQuery. It takes a collection of jQuery elements and returns the one at the given index.

```
$('.update_button').on("click",function(){
    var inputs = $(this).closest('.gridtable').find('input');
    var value1 = inputs.eq(0).val();
    var value2 = inputs.eq(1).val();
});
```